# Where/how do I filter with current_user data for recent_events with the timeline_fu plugin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, feed, timeline

I'm using the [timeline_fu plugin](https://github.com/jamesgolick/timeline_fu). I want to filter `recent_events` so that any event that has to do with the current user is not a `recent_event`. More specifically, if a user votes on a video, and the video belongs to the current user, I do not want it to be a `recent_event` for the current_user. In my case, this means that when `secondary_object.user == current_user`, I do not want the `recent_event` to be included. (I set the video as the secondary_object). I'm unsure of where and how to construct this logic.

This is the code that creates the `recent_events` association and filters them by `RECENT_EVENTS_CONDITIONS` (it basically filters them for when the actor of the event is a user that is followed by the current user)

```
    RECENT_EVENTS_CONDITION = '(actor_type = \'User\' AND actor_id IN (SELECT followed_id FROM relationships WHERE follower_id = #{id}))'
    has_many :recent_events, :class_name => "TimelineEvent",
                             :finder_sql => 'SELECT timeline_events.* FROM timeline_events
                                       WHERE ' + RECENT_EVENTS_CONDITION + '
                                       ORDER BY timeline_events.created_at DESC'
```

I could maybe put it in the SQL fragment or in a `:conditions` option for the has_many association?

Or I can put it in the `:if =>` option that the timeline_fu plugin provides for the creation of events. However this would not be ideal, because I do not have access to `current_user` here. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by added an `unless` statement in my view. However, I'm unsure if this is the best solution.